# Webpack 2 multiple js entries as well as babel and scss

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to update my Webpack to allow me to have multiple JS files, which also output as separate files.

Before I needed multiple JS files I used:

```
  entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/js/main.js',
    './src/scss/main.scss',
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/wp-content/themes/designdough/'),
    filename: 'assets/js/main.min.js',
  },
```

That worked great, but now i've updated it to be an object for multiple JS files, which works. But babel polyfill obviously doesn't and while I still get a file, it also creates a `scss.min.js`

```
  entry: {
        babel: 'babel-polyfill',
    app: './src/js/main.js',
    banner: './src/js/banner.js',
    scss: './src/scss/main.scss',
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/wp-content/themes/designdough/'),
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].min.js',
  },
```

How should babel and the scss be added to entry now?

Here's my full Webpack 2 config:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path    = require('path');

require("babel-polyfill");

let ExtractTextPlugin       = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let WebpackNotifierPlugin   = require('webpack-notifier');

let inProduction = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/js/main.js',
    './src/scss/main.scss',
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/wp-content/themes/designdough/'),
    filename: 'assets/js/main.min.js',
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
              url: false,
              minimize: true,
              sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
                fallback: 'style-loader'
            })
        },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: inProduction
        }),

        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: "WP Theme",
            contentImage: path.resolve("./public/favicon.ico"),
            alwaysNotify: true,
        })
    ]
};

if (inProduction) {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    )
}
```

Previous output:

```
assets/js/main.min.js   987 kB       0  [emitted]
            style.css  86.2 kB       0  [emitted]
```

Output now:

```
 assets/js/babel.min.js   264 kB       0  [emitted]  babel
   assets/js/app.min.js   726 kB       1  [emitted]  app
assets/js/banner.min.js  93.5 kB       2  [emitted]  banner
  assets/js/scss.min.js  2.52 kB       3  [emitted]  scss
              style.css  86.2 kB       3  [emitted]
```

Comment: Can you show the error please?

Comment: I've updated the post to include the outputs. But it's not an error of such, it's misconfiguration on my behalf, just don't know how to configure it correctly to use babel and scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like:

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
       'babel-polyfill' // put all your vendor in this
    ]
    app: './src/js/main.js',
    banner: './src/js/banner.js',
    // scss: './src/scss/main.scss', // remove this
  },
```

See the [document](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/). Entry point is just used for js file.

`ExtractTextPlugin` will extract css from js file.

Comment: Thanks! So do I import my `main.scss` file in `main.js`  now instead? Is there anyway I can keep the scss in my webpack like before `'./src/scss/main.scss'`?

Comment: `main: ['./src/js/main.js', './src/scss/main.scss'],` has done the job :)